# Facing issue while implementing error handling in Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement custom error handling in High charts using `Highcharts.error` function in angular 7 application but it is throwing error.

```js
Highcharts.error = function (code: string): void { };
```

> error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'error' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share some code of what you have implemented...

Comment: Started to implement the custom error handling while seeing an example from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/highcharts-error/
but I am unable to start the implementation because it is throwing error right away.

Comment: did you try this : https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/debugger-mode

Comment: yes I have this feature in my application, it will throw error in chart and console as well. I don't want to display error in console because I have refresh activity in my application the same error is displaying in console every time due to data issue and after sometime browser getting struck due to huge error logs. I want to get rid of this issue so decided to implement error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in Typescript is slightly different than in pure JS.
You can use `addEvent` method instead of assigning a new function to `Highcharts.error`

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.addEvent%3CT%3E

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-o4gml

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, "displayError", function(e: any): void {
  var chart = this,
    code = e.code;

  chart.renderer
    .text("Chart error " + code, 0, 0)
    .attr({
      fill: "red",
      zIndex: 20
    })
    .add()
    .align(
      {
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "middle"
      },
      null,
      "plotBox"
    );
});
```

The exact same approach is used in our debugger module: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/modules/debugger.src.ts